# Convergence in square mean

Tags: probability

If $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that $E(|X_n|)\to0$ but $E(X_n^2)\to 1$, does it imply that $X_n$ doesn't converge in square mean?

I can find a sequence that satisfies the two first conditions ($P(X_n=0)=1-1/n^2$ and $P(X_n=n)=1-1/n^2$), however I can't see how to show wether these two conditions imply no convergence in mean square.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $\mathbb P(X_n=n)=1/n^2$. In this case, it is true that $\mathbb E[X_n^2]=1$, but this does not mean it converges in mean square to $1$. For this to be the case we must have $$\mathbb E[|X_n-1|^2]\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0 $$ which is not true.

Answer (score 2):

> If $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that $E(|X_n|)\to0$ but $E(X_n^2)\to 1$, does it imply that $X_n$ doesn't converge in square mean?

If $X_n$ converges to something in square mean, it converges also in mean (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_mean)). But $X_n$ already converges in mean to $0$, while it doesn't converge in square mean to it. Therefore $X_n$ cannot converge in square mean to anything else either.